# Trying to bevel a design

Tags: bevel

So I have this simple piece I want to put a bevel around the outside.  I cant figure out how to get it to work.  I get how to do it on cubes and what not, but this has all these edges and lines in edit mode that it just blows up since they go in all directions.  I tried to use a modifier in regular mode but cant seem to grasp that either.[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of similar I imagine to working with text objects in Blender so ill demo on that,

Your topology starts like this, Or something near this:
[image]

Go to Mesh>Clean Up>Limited Dissolve, which basically dissolves all edges based on the angle of faces they are connected to.

[image]

Thatll give you this:

[image]

You might go through and clean up your edges a little bit, just to even out a few really long triangles or what not. This step might be not necessary. Some times blender has to have an edge in one spot to figure out how to make a weird Ngon stay together. If that edge is weird try to connect other vertices Around it and then use Ctrl+X to dissolve the bad one. You should be left with this: [image]

Then you can add your Bevel Modifier, Use these settings:[image]
, most importantly, Setting the Bevel method to Angle, otherwise it bevels every single edge, and set the Outer Miter to Arc to smooth out the sharp corners. Set the model to Smooth Shaded, check Harden Normals on the Bevel Modifier and you get this:[image]

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: That was exactly what i need, thank you very much.  I did have to do it a little different as I was instantly taxing my system into not responding.  But after limited dissolve I was able to just select the top and bottom faces and bevel that way to get exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much!